# looping through json in query

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I run loop over the json? I need to access each elements. I am using jquery/jscript

```
var k={
  "1":["Magic Moments","vodka","1000.00","1000",5,"5000.00"],
  "2":["Signature","whiskey","1000.00","1000",3,"3000.00"],
  "3":["McCallan 18","whiskey","25000.00","750",18,"450000.00"]
};
```

Comment: Try [Object.keys(k)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).  Look here for that, and other options: https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/

Comment: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 3):

```
Object.entries(k).forEach((key, val) => console.log(`key: ${key}\nvalue: ${val}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on objects too:

```js
$.each(k, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is JSON, first you should parse it.
**Example:**

```
const parsedObj = JSON.parse(yourJson)
```

and then use (credits to bugcatcher9000)

```
Object.entries(parsedObj).forEach(([key, val]) =>
console.log(`key: ${key}\nvalue: ${val}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript for...in loop for iterating object

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_object_loop_bracket